# Record type with multiple constructors

Tags: c#, .net, c#-9.0

How do I create **multiple constructors** for a record type in C#?

I created a record type like this:

```
public record Person(int Id, string FirstName, string LastName)
```

Now I want to introduce another constructor overload with no parameters, how can I do that?
In a normal class I would do something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        
    }

    public Person(int id, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2020/11/07/csharp-9-record-types-introduction-and-deep-dive/... Check the section with heading : Alternative Syntax to Define Record Types... it has some interesting explanation.. Always all parameters must be initialised in a record type. Else you just use a class..

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Simply add the constructor you want like this:

```
record Rank(int level, string description);

record Manager(string FirstName, Rank Rank) {
  public Manager() : this("", new Rank(0, "Entry")) { }

  // public Manager(string FirstName, Rank Rank) is auto generated
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can write your code like below:

```
public record Person
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
    //constructor
    public Person()
    {
        //init or do something
    }
    //overload constructor
    public Person(int id, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use optional arguments.

```
public record Person(int Id = default, string FirstName = null, string LastName = null);
```

Comment: It doesn't really solve the problem of creating overloads. What happens if I need 3 constructors?

Comment: It solves your problem because records aim to set fields in initializing phase. You should set fields like this `new Person(){ FirstName="Nadar" }`. Otherwise, use a class.

Comment: What if one of my properties is `string[]` and I don't want it to be null? This doesn't cover that. And making a class isn't a solution, it's a work around as you give up a lot of native functionality. So I don't accept this answer.

Answer (score 7):

you can write it like this:

```
public record Person(int Id,string FirstName,string LastName){
   public Person(YourDto item):this(item.Id,item.FirstName,item.LastName){} 
}
```

so, in the constructor you can pass your Dto item.

Answer (score 0):

You can also extend like so when you have a base record:

```
public record Person
{
    public Person(Guid? id = null) { }
}

public record Teacher : Person
{
    public Teacher(Guid id) : base(id) { }
    public Teacher(string firstName, string lastName) : base() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example extends a record with a default parameter that cannot be initialized with a compile-time constant:

```
public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName)
{
    public string[] Aliases = new string[0];

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string[] aliases)
        : this(firstName, lastName)
    {
        Aliases = aliases;
    }
}
```